# Can anyone help to understand the following errors where RabbitMQ is going in error state?

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I am getting this error again and again.

```
"operation none caused a connection exception connection_forced: "broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown'"
```

For the above error I have already found something from this https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1343027 i.e 
Rabbit can join the rabbitmq cluster if the controller-0 was rebooted,came up,started all the resources and only when everything works controller-1 goes for the reboot. In other words everything should work when rebooting one of the controllers. If,for some reason, controller-1 reboots while controller-0 not fully recovered after its reboot - things go wrong.

But I am not sure why is the error log file also showing me the below error:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 29-Dec-2019::17:44:26 === Mnesia('messaging@rabbit-2'): ** ERROR ** (ignoring core) ** FATAL ** mnesia_monitor crashed: {badarg, [{ets, lookup, [mnesia_decision, 'messaging@rabbit-3'], []}, {mnesia_recover, has_mnesia_down, 1, [{file, "mnesia_recover.erl"}, {line, 299}]}, {mnesia_monitor, check_mnesia_down, 2, [{file, "mnesia_monitor.erl"}, {line, 862}]}, {mnesia_monitor, handle_info, 2, [{file, "mnesia_monitor.erl"}, {line, 579}]}, {gen_server, try_dispatch, 4, [{file, "gen_server.erl"}, {line, 615}]}, {gen_server, handle_msg, 5, [{file, "gen_server.erl"}, {line, 681}]}, {proc_lib, init_p_do_apply, 3, [{file, "proc_lib.erl"}, {line, 240}]}]} state: {state, <0.745.0>, [], [], true, [], undefined, [], []}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says one system process of the Mnesia DB, `mnesia_monitor` is crashing when it tries to look up a value from an ETS table (`mnesia_decision`) owned by an other system process of the DB, `mnesia_recover`. This can only happen if the ETS table no longer exists, that is if the `mnesia_recover` has stopped.

This error message doesn't say why `mnesia_recover` has stopped. If it has crashed, there should be an other error message about that event in the log. But it is also possible that the whole Mnesia application has been stopping at that time, because the supervisor would stop `mnesia_recover` before `mnesia_monitor`. If that's the case, this error is just caused by bad timing: `mnesia_monitor` sees the `messaging@rabbit-3` node coming up at a point when Mnesia on its node is already shutting down.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Daniel. I found out that RabbitMQ was out of cluster for quite a long time. I followed the following procedure: 1)stopped the RabbitMQ service 2) deleted the logs at "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia" 2)started the service. This worked and now the RbbitMQ has been in the working state for few weeks without a single crash. This procedure was a test from my end but it worked.